# Creating ActionBar tab also calling its selectTab functions

Tags: java, android

I have a function `createTabs` in a parent class that create application bar tabs and attach `tabListener` to them and in tabListener's `onTabSelected` it checked for the selected tab and call its activity through intent.

Now in all the activity classes I call this function in `onCreate` method, to instantiate tabs on that activity.
Now issues is in `createTabs` when I am adding tabs in statements like:

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Event Feed")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_alarms)
                .setTabListener(tabListener),0,false);
```

It automatically calls `onTabSelected` listener method, when transfer the control to the activity class where I am against calling this function in `onCreate` method, to instantiate tabs, this sends my application in an infinite loop.

1. My Question is why `onTabSelected` is getting called after `.addTab`?
2. And what is the solution to come out of this infinite loop?

Please help:

createTabs method in parent activity class:
    public void createTabs(ActionBar actionBar) {

```
    try {
        // final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                int tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
                switch (tabPosition) {
                case 0:
                    Intent startFeedActivity = new Intent(
                            MainActivity.this, EventFeed.class);
                    startActivity(startFeedActivity);
                    break;
                case 1: {
                    Intent startWideActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            WideView.class);
                    startActivity(startWideActivity);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                    setContentView(R.layout.event_feed);
                    break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Event Feed")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_alarms)
                .setTabListener(tabListener),0,false);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Wide")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_Wide)
                .setTabListener(tabListener),1,true);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Report")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location_found)
                .setTabListener(tabListener),2,false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.getStackTraceString(e.getCause().getCause());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oops Batman!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

in Activity class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_feed);
    createTabs(getActionBar());
    loadFeed();
}
```

In debugger where it can be seen that `ActionBarImpl.selectTab` is getting called after `ActionBarImpl.addTab`

```
MainActivity$1.onTabSelected(ActionBar$Tab, FragmentTransaction) line: 44   
ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBar$Tab) line: 572    
ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBar$Tab, int, boolean) line: 511 
WideView(MainActivity). createTabs (ActionBar) line: 74 
WideView.onCreate(Bundle) line: 20  
WideView(Activity).performCreate(Bundle) line: 5133
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>What you need to do is set the listener *after* adding the tab:</strike>

```
ActionBar.Tab wideTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Wide")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_Wide);
actionBar.addTab(wideTab,1,true);
wideTab.setTabListener(tabListener);
```

You're right; that doesn't work. If you're duplicating this code across Activities (you shouldn't - it should go in a 'base' Activity and then your others should extend that), just bail out for the appropriate case out of your listeners `onTabSelected` method.

As a side note, I'd recommend looking into using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for your tab content, rather than Activities.

```
class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private int mTabPosition;

    public MyTabListener(int tabPosition) {
        mTabPosition = tabPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        int tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
        // If we're trying to select this already-selected tab, bail out.
        if (tabPosition == mTabPosition) return;
        switch (tabPosition) {
        case 0:
            Intent startFeedActivity = new Intent(
                    MainActivity.this, EventFeed.class);
            startActivity(startFeedActivity);
            break;
        case 1: {
            Intent startWideActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    WideView.class);
            startActivity(startWideActivity);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
            setContentView(R.layout.event_feed);
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And then when adding a tab:

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Event Feed")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_alarms)
            .setTabListener(new MyTabListener(0)),0,false);
```

Comment: trying your way it throws error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback`