# Android: Why is onTabSelected being called when tabs are created?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

When the action bar has tabs, I've noticed that onTabSelected is called when the activity loads on screen.  It also is being called whenever an orientation change occurs.  My code queries the database depending on the tab being selected, and displays the query results to the loaded layout.

My problem is when saving tab state, and the current selected tab is 1 or higher, on restore state, since onTabSelected is called by default on the 0 tab, it will be called again when restored state tab is 1 or higher.  This makes database query on tab 0 useless.

How to configure android that onTabSelected isn't called on tab creation or at least detect that this call is default and not user triggered?

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    int tabPos = tab.getPosition();
    switch(tabPos) {
    case 0:
        // query database and display result
        break;
    case 1:
        // a different query and display result
        break;
    case 2: ...
    }
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_TAB)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_TAB));
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_TAB, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

<strike>**Added complication:**
When the current selected tab is 0, and the orientation changes, onTabSelected is still called twice!  Once when the tabs are initially created, and 2nd time when onRestoreState restores the saved tab selected state, even though it is 0.</strike>

What I originally supposed was that onTabSelected was called twice, but I was mistaken.  It was my fragment onCreateView being called twice, some errors in fragment transaction that added the same fragment twice on orientation change.   onTabSelected is called once, and restore state calls onTabReselected is called too when the restored tab is also 0.

---

After scouring SO and google, I've found this question to have similar cause of problem.
[Creating ActionBar tab also calling its selectTab functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084931/creating-actionbar-tab-also-calling-its-selecttab-functions)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So after reviewing the reference docs on ActionBar from Google's Android site, addTab method is the one responsible for calling onTabSelected by default.

```
public abstract void addTab (ActionBar.Tab tab)
```

Add a tab for use in tabbed navigation mode. The tab will be added at the end of the list. If this is the first tab to be added it will become the selected tab.

**Parameters**
  *tab*     Tab to add

Incidentally, other overloaded methods exist that do not call onTabSelected.

```
public abstract void addTab (ActionBar.Tab tab, boolean setSelected)
```

So I used these alternative methods instead and it fixed the problem.
However, once the tabs are displayed, the first tab may appear selected even though it's not.  Clicking on it will call onTabSelected and not onTabReselected.

Comment: It works, obviously we have to set true only to a single tab in the ActionBar (creation phase). onTabSelected will be fired on every tab added with setSelected set to true.

Comment: I am calling addOnTabSelectedListener at that time onTabSelected is called.Can y ou please me?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it in this way:

Call `setupWithViewPager` before `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener`

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object :  TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {....}
.....
}
```

> because when you call **setupWithViewPager**, this will internally call
>   **setOnTabSelectedListener(new
>   ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));**

so you better call it before adding tabSelect Listener to tabLayout

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this (and ignore any typo please :-)) :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

boolean isConfigChanged;
int savedTabIndex;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     if(savedInstanceState != null){
        if(savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_TAB)) {
            savedTabIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_TAB);
          //getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedTabIndex); actually you do not need this
        }
        isConfigChanged = true;
    }

   // here add actionbar tabs

//...}
```

and in :

below code checks that if `configuration` changes and the user selected tab is `not zero` so this is default call and ignore but if `isConfigChanged == true` and the user selected tab is 0 you `must query DB` or if `isConfigChanged == false` you must query DB because it is first time that app is loading. a quick play may fit it to what you want.

```
   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(isConfigChanged && savedTabIndex != 0){
       isConfigChanged = false;
       return;
     }
    isConfigChanged = false;
    int tabPos = tab.getPosition();
    switch(tabPos) {
    case 0:
        // query database and display result
        break;
    case 1:
        // a different query and display result
        break;
    case 2: ...
    }
  }
```

remove onRestore

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_TAB, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: I think you're on to something there.  However, I've done more tests and the problem is more complicated than I first imagined.  For example, if the current tab is 0 and the orientation changes, onTabSelected is called twice!!  Once when the tabs are created, and 2nd time when onRestoreState restores the tab 0 selection.  I like your idea, I'll have to make improvements for this added complication I just mentioned.

Comment: just put another flag and change it in to the block of `case 0:` so the second time will ignore.

Comment: I'm not stopping you from editing your answer, by all means, please do.  I just wanted to inform you of that condition.

Comment: I've found a simpler solution.  I've posted it as answer.  But thanks for your inputs.